# How to check if one or more words exist in a url

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if there is one or more words in a url, how could I proceed?
I'm trying to check if a url has in it the category that a product has

I tried like this

```
const url = "http:/localhost/fast-food-ham/hotdog.html";

const words = "Fast Food";
console.log(
  url.toLowerCase().includes(words.toLowerCase())
);
```

Comment: That depends entirely on the URL format you're expecting. Will URLs follow a pre-defined format?

Comment: No, is not pre-defined

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

```
const url = "http:/localhost/fast-food-ham/hotdog.html";

const words = /fast(-|\s)food/i;

if(url.match(words)) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

The above code prints `true` if the url contains `fast food` or `fast-food`; `false` otherwise.
If you need to print `true` if is there a character that is not a space between `fast` and `food` (eg: `fast+food`, `fast_food`) you can add `\S` for the captures in the regular expression:

```
const words = /fast(-|\s|\S)/i
```

The last `/i` means that the case of the text is ignoring. Since that you don't have to `url.toLowerCase()`.

Learn more about regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can split the string to words:

```
const url = "http:/localhost/fast-food-ham/hotdog.html";

    const words = "Fast Food";
    words_lst=words.split(" ");
    let isexist=false;
    for (let word of words_lst)
         if(url.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase())){
            isexist=true;
            break;
        }
    console.log(isexist)
```

have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
let text = "http:/localhost/fast-food-ham/hotdog.html";

 let words = "Fast Food";
let a = words.replace(/ /g,"-").toLowerCase();
var regex = new RegExp( a, 'i' );
 let result = text.match(regex);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if something is true or false, you will need to use an `if statement.` keep in mind that `includes` is **case-sensetive**.

```js
// to check url as a given variable
const url = "http:/localhost/fast-food-ham/hotdog.html";

if (url.includes("fast-food")) {
  console.log("Yes");
} else {
  console.log("No");
}


// to check current page URL
const currentURL = location.href;

if (currentURL.includes("html")) {
  console.log("Yes");
} else {
  console.log("No");
}


// to check if it includes one of multiple words in current page URL

if (currentURL.includes("css" && "gg" && "stack")) {
  console.log("Yes");
} else {
  console.log("No");
}



// to check if it includes multiple words in current page URL

if (currentURL.includes("stack" || ".com")) {
  console.log("Yes");
} else {
  console.log("No");
}
```